# Form Array Overlapping

Tags: php, html, arrays

i'm making a contact form but im trying a dropbox so you can select more than 1 option but when i use the array to select multiple it overlaps the other dropbox and goes all weird here is the array with php. pic of the bug prntscr dot com / 8d2c5

```
<select name="skills[ ]" multiple>
    <option value="Permaculture">Permaculture</option>
    <option value="Recycling">Recycling</option>
    <option value="Sewing">Sewing</option>
</select>

/select>
<label for="select" class="select">
<select name="participate[]" id="participate" multiple>
    <option value="" selected>When can you participate?</option>
    <option value="3-6 months from now">3-6 months from now</option>
    <option class="purple" value="6-12 months">6-12 months</option>
    <option value="Next Year (2016)">Next Year (2016)</option>
    <option class="purple" value="Community Crowd Funding">Community Crowd Funding</option>
</select>
```

In php i put

```
  $skills = implode(",", $_POST['skills']);
```

Comment: You have a broken <select> tab on the 8th line - could that be causing an issue?

Comment: Please can you tell us what you mean by all weird. What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: the 2 drop box's over lap when i use the array so i can select multiple selections skype? i will show you via image what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

The image link does not show, and if you have exactly that same code then you have a missing open tag (<)  ...... thats probably your problem

Comment: Ok i fixed the bug but i don't think it's working still i want to be able to select multiple selections in the drop box section so when i send email it has selected multiple skills in the drop box can you help via skype pls.

Answer (score 1):

Close the select tag like `</select>`. But you don't have a select open for the closing at line 7, you can delete that line.